# Find the most frequent elements in an array of Integers

Tags: arrays, c

I have to find all of the elements which have the maximum frequency. For example, if array a={1,2,3,1,2,4}, I have to print as 1, also 2. My code prints only 2. How to print the second one?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define n 6
int main(){
    int a[n]={1,2,3,1,2,4};
    int counter=0,mostFreq=-1,maxcnt=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++){
            if(a[i]==a[j]){
                counter++;
            }
        }
        if(counter>maxcnt){
            maxcnt=counter;
            mostFreq=a[i];
        }
    }
    printf("The most frequent element is: %d",mostFreq);
}
```

Comment: count all elements, maintain a list of counters, extract the 2 biggest values of this list.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: The problem states to find all the elements which have the maximum frequency, not just two.

Comment: The title and the question don't match, @EricPostpischil — which is not as uncommon as it should be.

Comment: Could your input data be wildly big numbers (`-12345678`, `987654321`, etc), or are they constrained to be tiny and positive?  You're going to have to count how many occurrences there are for each number in the array, find which is the maximum number of occurrences, and then print the numbers that have that many occurrences.  And the magnitude of the numbers affects how you do the counting for each number in the array.

Comment: Style guide: generally, you should use upper-case names for constants such as `n`.  It's a convention in C dating back to the earliest years.  Seeing `int a[n];` immediately sets off alarms about "why is this a VLA (variable-length array) and where is `n` initialized".  Seeing `int a[N];` would not set off such alarms.  Of course, there's nothing to stop someone creating `int N;`, but conventions help avoid extra work.

Answer (score 2):

> How to print the second one?

The goal it not only to print a potential 2nd one, but all the all of the elements which have the maximum frequency.

---

OP already has code that determines the maximum frequency.  Let us build on that.  Save it as `int target = mostFreq;`.

Instead of printing `mostFreq`, a simple (still O(n*n)) approach would perform the same 2-nested `for()` loops again.  Replace this 2nd:

```
    if(counter>maxcnt){
        maxcnt=counter;
        mostFreq=a[i];
    }
```

With:

```
    if(counter == target){
        ; // TBD code: print the a[i] and counter.
    }
```

---

For large `n`, a more efficient approach would sort `a[]` (research `qsort()`).  Then walk the sorted `a[]` twice, first time finding the maximum frequency and the 2nd time printing values that match this frequency.

This is O(n* log n) in time and O(n) in memory (if a copy of the original array needed to preserve the original).  If also works well with negative values or if we change the type  of `a[]` from `int` to `long long`, `double`, etc.

Comment: I think you should be able to walk the sorted list once.  You keep track of the current value and current count, the maximum count so far and a list of values with that count.  If you get a new, larger current count, then you zap the list of values and add the new one with the new maximum count.  That only requires a single pass over the sorted array.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler True, 1 pass, yet with another list.  With careful coding, code could use the sorted list it is reading to store the max count list. - so more memory not needed.  OTOH, we still need to make a pass through the max count list to print it.

Answer (score 1):

The standard student solution to such problems would be this:

- Make a second array called frequency, of the same size as the maximum *value* occurring in your data.
- Init this array to zero.
- Each time you encounter a value in the data, use that value as an index to access the frequency array, then increment the corresponding frequency by 1. For example `freq[value]++;`.
- When done, search through the frequency array for the largest number(s). Optionally, you could sort it.

Comment: The pessimist that I am predicts a "give the code please" upcoming. But I consider this a helpful and correct answer to the question as asked.

Comment: This may end up in a very large array

Comment: @davidriod Not for the usual student homework assignments where the teacher picked 0 to 10 or so on purpose.

Comment: sure, but if it's an algorithm class, this may not pass the space complexity evaluation.

Comment: @davidriod Whereas sorting and applying some manner of "greedy" search algorithm might not pass execution speed evaluation, so... don't optimize until you need to? Also on that topic, most algorithm classes fail to take things such as branch prediction or cache memories in account... so the code might look very different depending on if it's for beginner homework, or for algorithm class homework or for use on real-world computers.

Answer (score 0):

We can (potentially) save some effort in an approach with unsorted data by creating an array of boolean flags to determine whether we need to count an element at all.

For the array `{1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4}` we do have nested for loops, so O(n) complexity, but we can avoid the inner loop entirely for *repeated* numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void) {
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4};
    size_t arr_size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr);

    bool checked[arr_size];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < arr_size; i++) checked[i] = false;

    unsigned int counts[arr_size];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < arr_size; i++) counts[i] = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < arr_size; i++) {
        if (!checked[i]) {
            checked[i] = true;
            counts[i]++;
            for (size_t j = i+1; j < arr_size; j++) {
                if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
                    checked[j] = true;
                    counts[i]++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    unsigned int max = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < arr_size; i++) {
        if (counts[i] > max) max = counts[i];
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < arr_size; i++) {
        if (counts[i] == max)
            printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```